# C++ Game Modification - Toggle Menu Options

Tags: c++

I'm working on a game modification for GTAV. I'm trying to achieve toggling options in the menu itself. I have this so far:

```
char* PlayerOptions[8] = {
    "Invisible",
    "Godmode",
    "No Ragdoll",
    "Super Jump",
    "Fast Run",
    "No Police",
    "Character Options >",
    "Cash Options >"
};

// ...

for (int i = 0; i < MenuSizes[selectedMenu]; i++) {
    if (i == selectedIndex) {
        // draw hovered option to screen
        DRAW_TEXT(PlayerOptions[i], 0.050, 0.150 + (0.1 * ((double)i / 3)), 0.35, 0.35, 0, false, false, false, false, selected_text_R, selected_text_G, selected_text_B, 255);
        DRAW_TEXT("OFF", 0.175, 0.150 + (0.1 * ((double)i / 3)), 0.25, 0.25, 0, false, false, false, false, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    } else {
        // draw non-hovered option to screen
        DRAW_TEXT(PlayerOptions[i], 0.050, 0.150 + (0.1 * ((double)i / 3)), 0.35, 0.35, 0, false, false, false, false, 255, 255, 255, 255);
        DRAW_TEXT("OFF", 0.175, 0.150 + (0.1 * ((double)i / 3)), 0.25, 0.25, 0, false, false, false, false, 255, 255, 255, 255);
    }
}
```

I'm looking for a way to enable/disable an option and display it on screen when its enabled. I've thought about something like this:

```
char* PlayerOptions[8] = {
                         // name, isEnabled, isSubmenu
    char* Invisible[3] = {"Invisible", false, false},
    char* Godmode[3] = {"Godmode", false, false},
    char* Ragdoll[3] = {"No Ragdoll", false, false},
    char* SuperJump[3] = {"Super Jump", false, false},
    char* FastRun[3] = {"Fast Run", false, false},
    char* NoPolice[3] = {"No Police", false, false},
    char* CharacterOptions[3] = {"Character Options", false, true},
    char* CashOptions[3] = {"Cash Options", false, true},
};
```

Would something like this be possible and how would I access these/change these values, e.g. when I use a menu item, how can I change `isEnabled` to `true` for that item?

Or if anybody has a better suggestion for this, please suggest them! I'm desperately looking for an answer for this, I have been looking for a few days already! Major thanks!

---

## **EDIT**

Based on the given comment, this is what I have at the moment:

```
struct PlayerOptions {
    char* name;
    int isEnabled;
    int isSubmenu;
};
```

Comment: You can't do `char* Ragdoll[3] = {"No Ragdoll", false, false},` because that defines an array of three strings and your three values are not strings.  Instead you should make a struct called PlayerOption which contains three items (a string and two booleans) and then make PlayerOptions be an array of eight of these PlayerOption structs.  You can still initialize all the items in the array in one place.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Can you possibly show an example? I'm pretty much noob level at C++. I appreciate your answer!

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I have edited my question with the code I'm currently struggling with in the hope of you helping me further with it.

Comment: This would be how you'd declare this structure: https://ideone.com/eoHKqT

Comment: Then you go through the elements like `DRAW_TEXT(PlayerOptions[i].name, ...` and such.

Comment: May I ask what you are using to mod the game?

Comment: @Havenard Hi, thank you for thinking in a solution. With your help and the help of Jerry I can finish my project. I use the Native Caller of 2much4u to mod the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have tagged the question with C++ but it is clear that you are using C syntax, so I will provide two answers: one with C syntax and one with C++

With C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define false 0
#define true 1

typedef struct
{
   char* name;
   short isEnabled;
   short isSubMenu;
} PlayerOption;

PlayerOption playerOptions[] = {
   { "Invisible",         false, false },
   { "Godmode",           false, false },
   { "No Ragdoll",        false, false },
   { "Super Jump",        false, false },
   { "Fast Run",          false, false },
   { "No Police",         false, false },
   { "Character Options", false, true  },
   { "Cash Options",      false, true  }
};

/* you could just use const int numPlayerOptions = 8 here instead... */
/* the advantage of this is that you don't need to change this line  */
/* when you change the array                                         */
const int numPlayerOptions = sizeof(playerOptions) / sizeof(PlayerOption);

int main()
{
   int i;

   /* update enabled value */
   playerOptions[3].isEnabled = true;

   /* print the array */
   for(i=0;i<numPlayerOptions;i++)
       printf("%s %s %s\n",
           playerOptions[i].name,
           playerOptions[i].isEnabled?"true":"false",
           playerOptions[i].isSubMenu?"true":"false"
       );

   return 0;
}
```

With C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct PlayerOption
{
   std::string name;
   bool isEnabled;
   bool isSubMenu;
};

std::vector<PlayerOption> playerOptions
{
   { "Invisible",         false, false },
   { "Godmode",           false, false },
   { "No Ragdoll",        false, false },
   { "Super Jump",        false, false },
   { "Fast Run",          false, false },
   { "No Police",         false, false },
   { "Character Options", false, true  },
   { "Cash Options",      false, true  }
};

int main()
{
   // update enabled value
   playerOptions[3].isEnabled = true;

   // print the vector
   for(PlayerOption option : playerOptions)
       std::cout << std::boolalpha
          << " " << option.name
          << " " << option.isEnabled
          << " " << option.isSubMenu
          << " " << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will certainly help me along! Thanks a ton!